# Will SQL Server 2016 support Python through external script?

Tags: python, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016 currently supports R through `sp_execute_external_script` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604368.aspx.

The syntax allows for a language parameter with the only current valid language being R.. Has there been any chatter or even official sources stating Python (or another specific language) will be supported in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is old but I found this article by accident and SQL Server 2017 will support Python based on information released today.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/04/19/python-in-sql-server-2017-enhanced-in-database-machine-learning/

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for Python with SQL Server 2016.
SQL Server 2016 supports only R as of now .
SQL Server 2017 has support for Python and R both.

SQL Server 2017
After running SQL Server setup, don't forget these important steps:

- Enable the external script execution feature by running
  sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1.

  2. Restart the server.
  3. Ensure that the service that calls the external run time has necessary permissions.
  4. Ensure that your SQL login or Windows user account has necessary permissions to connect to the server, to read data, and to create any
     database objects required by the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being late to the party. During SQL Pass 2015 it was mentioned that in the future there would possibly be support for Python and Julia.

As for now, March 2017, nothing more has been said, and right now R is the only supported language.

Niels

Comment: Thanks, I also asked on one of their blog entries ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/01/10/sql-server-r-services-why-did-we-build-it/)) and the author said they have plans to support other languages but no timeframe was given. "Yes, we have plans to support other languages like Python in the future. The extensiblity framework in engine was designed with this goal in mind & it is not specific to R integration only"